# Applying Attribute Filter and Spatial Filter simultaneously (GDAL - Python)

Tags: python, gdal

quick question on something that has to be simple, but I'm getting stuck on. I want to use an `Attribute Filter` and a `Spatial Filter` simultaneously.

I have two vector files (an overlaying grid and a stream). I want to iteratively select road segments that fall within each grid square and that have a specific attribute value for `length`.

I've been using -

```
roads.SetSpatialFilter(grid_geometry)

roads.SetAttributeFilter("Length = 'xxx'")
```

However, regardless of which filter I use first, applying the second filter resets the process (so I either get the attribute subset or the spatial subset, not both).

Comment: Can you try `roads = roads.SetSpatialFilter(grid_geometry)` and then `roads = roads.SetAttributeFilter("Length = 'xxx'")`? I haven't checked but it is probably making copies rather than modifying `roads` in-place.

Comment: Thanks for that! Unfortunately not a programmer by trade!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my comment, you need to do this instead:

```
roads = roads.SetSpatialFilter(grid_geometry)
roads = roads.SetAttributeFilter("Length = 'xxx'")
```

GDAL's `SetSpatialFilter` returns the `Layer` instance the method is called on, rather than [modifying it in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675506/python-change-variable-in-place). Therefore you need to capture the returned value. It may as well be the `roads` variable overriding `roads`.